# The clique number of zero-divisor graphs

Tags: graph-theory, commutative-algebra

If $R$ is finite commutative ring with exactly $8$ elements, show that the clique number of the zero-divisor graph is $2$.

**Edit.** Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $Z(R)$ be the set of all zero-divisors of $R$. Then the *zero-divisor graph* $Γ(R)$ is a simple graph with vertices $Z(R)^*=Z(R)-\{0\}$ and for two distinct elements $x$ and $y$ in $Z(R)$, $x$ and $y$ are *adjacent* if $xy=0$. It is clear that $Γ(R)=\emptyset$ if and only if $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: in my question R is locally ring with Zd(R)=P, where P is the only prime ideal in R which also maximal.

Comment: What is a "zero divisor graph"?

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is wrong!

Take $R=\mathbb F_2[X_1,X_2]/(X_1,X_2)^2$. Then $|R|=8$, $Z(R)^*=\{x_1,x_2,x_1+x_2\}$ and $x_1x_2=x_1(x_1+x_2)=x_2(x_1+x_2)=0$, so the clique number of $R$ is $3$. (Note that $R$ is exactly what you want it: $R$ is local and $Z(R)=\{0,x_1,x_2,x_1+x_2\}$ is the only prime ideal of $R$.)